# Vertical Navigation issue

Tags: html, css

So the navigation bar is meant to be the `height` of the page and is fixed, so will always show, even when the user scrolls down the page.
However my `.nav` is currently looking like [this](http://i59.tinypic.com/2n05to0.jpg)

Help would be greatly appreciated. Also, when creating a responsive website, what should the image size be? Like when creating the image on Photoshop, how large should the canvas be the ensure the image isn't blurry?

HTML and CSS is as follows

```css
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  position: fixed;
  top: -15px;
  left: -10px;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  background-color: #232121;
  /*padding-bottom: 73.5px;*/
  padding-left: 25px;
  /*padding-top: 20px;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.nav li a:hover {
  color: #00b4ff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.sub-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #232121;
  color: white;
}
.sub-nav li a {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.sub-nav li a:hover {
  color: #00b4ff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="logo1.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="salesandmotivation.html">SALES AND MOTIVATION</a>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li><a href="salessuccess.html">SALES SUCCESS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="motivation.html">MOTIVATION</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="propertyinvestment.html">PROPERTY INVESTMENT</a>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li><a href="listings.html">CURRENT LISTINGS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li><a href="salessuccess.html">SUBSCRIBE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html">CONNECT</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="facebook.com">
      <img src="facebook.jpg" alt="facebook" class="facebook">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="twitter.com">
      <img src="twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" class="twitter">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="linkedin.com">
      <img src="linkedin.jpg" alt="linkedin" class="linkedin">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: As for your second question, the size of the images depends on the context of the image. [2x resolution for retina displays](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/29850/do-i-need-to-create-my-images-at-twice-the-pixel-dimensions-on-a-retina-display).

Comment: full website code wasn't really needed since your problem is only related to your `.nav`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you are having your `background-color: #232121` in your  `.nav li a` just changed to your `.nav` and  your `.nav` was set `top:-15px`, I changed for `top:0`

**SNIPPET:**

```css
.nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 25%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: -10px;
  background-color: #232121;
}
.nav li a {
  display: block;
  /*padding-bottom: 73.5px;*/
  padding: 0 25px;
  /*padding-top: 20px;*/
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  font-weight: 600;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
}
.nav li a:hover {
  color: #00b4ff;
  text-decoration: none;
}
.nav li a img {
  max-width: 100%
}
.sub-nav {
  list-style-type: none;
  background-color: #232121;
  color: white;
}
.sub-nav li a {
  font-weight: 400;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
}
.sub-nav li a:hover {
  color: #00b4ff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
<ul class="nav">
  <li>
    <a href="index.html">
      <img src="//lorempixel.com/300/300" alt="logo" class="logo">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a>
  </li>
  <li><a href="salesandmotivation.html">SALES AND MOTIVATION</a>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li><a href="salessuccess.html">SALES SUCCESS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="motivation.html">MOTIVATION</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="propertyinvestment.html">PROPERTY INVESTMENT</a>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li><a href="listings.html">CURRENT LISTINGS</a>
      </li>
      <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
    <ul class="sub-nav">
      <li><a href="salessuccess.html">SUBSCRIBE</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="index.html">CONNECT</a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="facebook.com">
      <img src="facebook.jpg" alt="facebook" class="facebook">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="twitter.com">
      <img src="twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" class="twitter">
    </a>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a href="linkedin.com">
      <img src="linkedin.jpg" alt="linkedin" class="linkedin">
    </a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, it is working however when I zoom in, my logo jumps out of the navigation box? Please see post for attached image

Answer (score 0):

We could use a bit more code, to figure what is going on with your particular website; just pasting the `nav` code isn't very helpful.

That being said, let's keep things simple. This how you create a [basic fixed sidebar nav](http://jsfiddle.net/961mm314/). Obviously a lot depends on your specific code, but since we don't have that, we can only guess what's going on and I'm guessing you didn't set `height` to `100%` on the `nav`'s parent element and upstream to the other parents or `body`.

If you supply more details, perhaps we can elaborate as to what is going on.

```css
body {
    height: 100%;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
}

main {
    background: red;
    height: 1000px;
    padding-left: 100px;
}

aside {
    background: lightblue;
    height: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<aside>
    links here
</aside>
<main>
    this is your main content
</main>
```

Comment: The code for the rest of the website has been added!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the .nav is having 100% height now, but the problem is that it doesn't have the background color. You should set background-color: #232121; to .nav too. 
As of the cropped words, you have to give the div a width to make sure the words would not be out of boundary.

```css
.nav {
      background-color: #232121;
      height: 100%;
      width: 225px;
      position: fixed;
      top: 0;
      left: -10px;
      list-style-type: none;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 0;
      background-color: #232121;
}
        
.nav li a {
      display: block;
      background-color: #232121;
      width: 200px;
      /*padding-bottom: 73.5px;*/
      padding-left: 25px;
      /*padding-top: 20px;*/
      text-decoration: none;
      color: white;
      font-weight:600;
      letter-spacing: 2px;
}
        
.nav li a:hover {
      color: #00b4ff;
      text-decoration: none;            
}
        
.sub-nav {
      list-style-type: none;
      background-color: #232121;
      color: white; 
}
         
.sub-nav li a {
      font-weight: 400;
      letter-spacing: 1px;
      padding: 0;
      width: 185px;
}
          
.sub-nav li a:hover {
      color: #00b4ff;
      text-decoration: none;
      font-weight: 400;
}
```

```html
 <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html"><img src="logo1.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo"></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="salesandmotivation.html">SALES AND MOTIVATION</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav"> 
                <li><a href="salessuccess.html">SALES SUCCESS</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="motivation.html">MOTIVATION</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="propertyinvestment.html">PROPERTY INVESTMENT</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav"> 
                <li><a href="listings.html">CURRENT LISTINGS</a></li> 
                    <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            <ul class="sub-nav"> 
                <li><a href="salessuccess.html">SUBSCRIBE</a></li> 
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">CONNECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="facebook.com"><img src="facebook.jpg" alt="facebook" class="facebook"></a></li>
        <li><a href="twitter.com"><img src="twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" class="twitter"></a></li>
        <li><a href="linkedin.com"><img src="linkedin.jpg" alt="linkedin" class="linkedin"></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

edit your Css like:

```
.nav {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100px;
    width: 100%;
    position: fixed;
    left: -10px;
    /*border: 1px solid red;*/
}
.nav li
{
    display: inline;
}
.nav li a {
    background-color: #232121;
    /*padding-bottom: 73.5px;*/
    padding-left: 25px;
    /*padding-top: 20px;*/
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    font-weight:600;
    letter-spacing: 2px;
}
```

And html file to :

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Learning Input</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head> 

<body>
    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="index.html"><img src="logo1.jpg" alt="logo" class="logo"></a></li>
        <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
        <li><a href="products.html">PRODUCTS</a></li>
        <li><a href="salesandmotivation.html">SALES AND MOTIVATION</a>
            <!-- <ul class="sub-nav"> 
                <li><a href="salessuccess.html">SALES SUCCESS</a></li> 
                <li><a href="motivation.html">MOTIVATION</a></li>
            </ul> -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="propertyinvestment.html">PROPERTY INVESTMENT</a>
            <!-- <ul class="sub-nav"> 
                <li><a href="listings.html">CURRENT LISTINGS</a></li> 
                <li><a href="testimonials.html">TESTIMONIALS</a></li>
            </ul> -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a>
            <!-- <ul class="sub-nav"> 
                <li><a href="salessuccess.html">SUBSCRIBE</a></li> 
            </ul> -->
        </li>
        <li><a href="index.html">CONNECT</a></li>
        <li><a href="facebook.com"><img src="facebook.jpg" alt="facebook" class="facebook"></a></li>
        <li><a href="twitter.com"><img src="twitter.jpg" alt="twitter" class="twitter"></a></li>
        <li><a href="linkedin.com"><img src="linkedin.jpg" alt="linkedin" class="linkedin"></a></li>
    </ul>
</body>
</html>
```